Switching WhatsApp from one phone to another
The Samsung Galaxy Z Fold 4 inner screen has a problem and I got a replacement. Same phone.  I can't transfer my messages from WhatsApp on the old phone. It seems my backup to Google hasn't worked for 5 months.  I can't seem to back up. I select the backup feature, and it requests for me to log in to Google with my fingerprint. I do, and then I get a grey-on-white band with a backing-up sign, but nothing seems to happen.  No spinning icon, just nothing.
I had to switch my WhatsApp back onto my old phone (which still has the messages).  It also seems the Google account associated with WhatsApp on each phone may be different and I'm not sure how to adjust that.

It's likely that your WhatsApp backup is deleted from your Google drive. From WhatsApp FAQ

WhatsApp backups that haven’t been updated in 5 months might be automatically deleted by Google

(Emphasis supplied)

You can check the storage used by WhatsApp here
to confirm.

If  backup is deleted, there is nothing you can do, except try local backup as mentioned in answer here (third bullet point under other options. I haven't tried this, so can't help with it but I see people claiming it works for them).

Regarding accounts, WhatsApp is tied to your main account, the account you used to set up the phone for first time (you can add other accounts later) and for the backup to be restored you have to use the same account (use it to set up second phone)

